# zsh: fork failed: resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: macos, terminal, process

Recently, my terminal always dead after about 10 hours, and files cannot open, I can do nothing to this computer but restart it.

when it recovered, I find that a process named `OriginalModuled` generate child process instantly, and after kill this process, the total process num decreased, but this process will restart automatically.

[process picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYA48.png)

I searched about this process, and find the file path is under `/var/root/Library/Application Support/.OriginalModule.dp`, what is this? Can I delete it? How can I solve this?

Comment: [It's might be helpful](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2244853)

Comment: Thank you, I change the folder name from `.OriginalModule.dp` to `.OriginalModule.dp.bak`, and it solved with no error